# Prevent Single Line TextView Ellipses constrained by Label in Constraint Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have two TextViews that are aligned vertically with the top TextView acting as a label for the bottom TextView. We can call them testLabel and testText. To keep them left aligned, testText has constraint of start -> startOf to testLabel. These TextViews are position in the right, top corner of the parent. testLabel has an end -> endOf constraint to the parent with a margin value. The issue is that the label can vary in length, and when the label's length is a value small enough, the label will properly update its position based on the margin and constraint setting with the parent but that also causes the text align its start.That results in the text going off screen, showing an ellipses if the text is long enough. I can say that text's length is Perry much constant. I created a simple Activity to illustrate the problem. 
Here's the case when the label isn't small enough and everything looks ok:
[image]
When the label is small enough:
[image]

Here's the xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="MonkeyBars"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/testLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/testLabel" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I would like to happen is the constraint realizing that the text is going to overflow and to instead only fulfill the margin up to the point that the text doesn't overflow. I'm sure there's something I can do programmatically but hope that this is something I can implement in the layout.

Comment: can you show, what exactly behavior you want?

Comment: I'll update the information but essentially I want the label and textview to remain left aligned without either one's text causing the ellipses and that the label is the only textview that can vary in length

Comment: So, it would work if the two views are each the width of the wider view?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from **testText** TextView:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/testLabel"
```

and Add this line in **textLabel** TextView:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/testText"
```

Hope it will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to constraint start of TextView on the top to start of TextView on bottom?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/testLabel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/testText"
        ... />
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/testText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="MonkeyBars"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/testLabel" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So the issue is the label is variable length. So if the label's text is long enough it will cause the ellipse for the label. Now what I could do is make the margin for the text big enough to cover the maximum length the label could be.

Comment: You don't need to increase margin of label. Just constraint the start of label to start of longest TextView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both textview to be left aligned and label can vary in length then try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="MonkeyBars"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/testLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/testLabel" />
```